# connection refused while connecting elasticsearch from logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

[Ruby-0-Thread-9: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.9.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:213] elasticsearch - Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://localhost:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connect to localhost:9200 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused"}

i have tried network.host: 0.0.0.0 but not worked